# Acer Aspire microphone issue

Tags: sound, acer, microphone, aspire

I have got an Acer Aspire 7750G: [More info](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/acer-aspire-7750g-9657/4507-3121_7-34741237.html)

It has been running Ubuntu since I bought the laptop (`12.10` as of now), but a few updates  ago, I lost my microphone.

It doesn't recognise the internal mic or the mic jack (although `alsa` seems to recognise it).

I have been looking around, and I fixed it, but this was only temporary, after a reboot my mic was gone again. I haven't been able to find the fix, so I wanted to know whatever you guys know what I have to do to fix this.

result of `aplay -l`:

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

[EDIT]: I just noticed that unplugging the mic works. restart ing pulse or anything doesnt work, but replugging the mic works..... strange. But I dont want to replug the mic everytime I boot.

Thanks in advance.

ps I am reading that many people are encountering this issue...

Comment: This may be a bug. How did you fix it?

Comment: If you found a fix to this problem, could you add an answer. Or if haven't been fixed, an update of the issue.

Comment: My microphone works now, I have no clue why, I guess some update. I can't remember if I reinstalled ubuntu or not, better purge this thread.